# php can connect remotely to mysql but not locally

Tags: php, mysql

UPDATE:
I tried having my php file in windows and connect to the mysql server remotely in linux using the code below

mysql_connect('10.128.xx.xx', 'jflim', 'helloworld');

this works! but when i tried uploading the same php file in linux(server) and changing the connection string to

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

its not working.. its also not showing any error message. php codes are working fine without database connection. Im not sure what the problem is now. many thanks

Comment: In the file, uploaded to linux machine you must use localhost, if mysql is located on the server, you uploaded the file to

Comment: how do you know the live linux mysql server credentials are also 'root', '' ?

Comment: Any remote thing can not be 'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

If you upload the .php file in the server where the mysql server is running you should use 'localhost'. But if the script is located in another machine replace the 'localhost' with an ip address or url (www.example.com).

Apart from that, make sure you use the right username and pw.

Comment: I tried having my php file in windows and connect to the mysql server remotely in linux using the code below

mysql_connect('10.128.xx.xx', 'jflim', 'helloworld');

this works but when i tried uploding the same php file in linux and changing the connection string to 

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

its not working.. its also not showing any error message. php codes are working fine without database connection. Im not sure what the problem is now. thanks

Comment: Are you sure root doesn't have a password? Try the credentials you use in your windows machine. i.e. `mysql_connect('localhost','jflim','hellowold')` and see if this works. If it works, it is a user('root') problem.